# Prevent FlatList re-rendering off-screnn components of which the props changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the following `FlatList` in a React Native TS project:

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={styles(styleProps).scrollCont}
  data={lineIds}
  renderItem={(itemData) => (
    <Row id={itemData.item} lineIdx={itemData.index} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item}
/>
```

This represents a matrix.

The items which are use to iterate are the IDs of `Row` components.

Each row is complex, as it has children and grand children component.

The App has a complex state, so I use Redux to run it.

Each Row has few Cell components as children.
Each Cell has a CellText component as an only child.

When a user presses any cell in the matrix, it should grey out the text in all the other cells.

This is how it is done inside CellText, using useSeletor from redux:

export default memo(function CellText({ highlightEn, text}: CellTextProps) {

```
const highlightAny: boolean = useSelector<RootState, boolean>(state => state.mat.highlightAny);

const styleProps: CellTextStyleProps = { highlightEn: highlightEn, highlightAny: linehighlightAny }
```

The styleProps are later passed down to a styling component which should gray out text if any other cell is pressed other than itself.

That means that if the user presses the first cell, we are to render *all* of the other cells in the matrix in order to grey out their text, which is very slow.
This is also unnecessary as most gray out cells are off the screen anyway.

I have added a print to see what renders when I press:
console.log(`rendering cell ${text} in row ${rowIdx}`)

And each time I press a cell, all the CellTexts in the matrix re-render.

`FlatList`, it seems, *does* re-render components of which the props have changed, even if these components are currently off screen. useSelector, as far I've seen, triggeres re-renders unpon a value's change, and it seems to do so in these components as well.

Is there a way to avoid this, and re-render only the components which are visible to the user?

Have done some searching, but the issue didn't seem to come up a lot.
Most solutions talk about improving performance via memoization, but I've already done this, and now trying to improve by preventing *real* re-renders of offscreen components.

Comment: This react native [article](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration) may help.

Comment: The `FlatList` component should already be optimized, i.e. virtualized, a.k.a. "windowed", so there should not be much of anything you need to do for performance. That said, if you are seeing performance issues it's likely somewhere else and not anything with `FlatList`. How exactly are you measuring the rendering performance? Have you run any audits to see where any bottlenecks exist? How exactly are you validating that off-screen components are really being rerendered? Please [edit] to provide better details.

Answer (score 0):

try to do

```
const renderItem = useCallback((itemData) => (
    <Line id={itemData.item} lineIdx={itemData.index} />
),[]);

<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles(styleProps).scrollCont}
    data={lineIds}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item}
/>
```

avoid use anonymous function on renderItem for improve the performance

Comment: The anonymous function is fine as there's only the one reference to it.

Comment: You can see in the documentation of react native https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#avoid-anonymous-function-on-renderitem

Comment: I don't think the "performance hit" of instantiating a one-line callback function that simply returns some JSX is what is causing any problem for the OP. I expect suggesting to use more [basic components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#use-basic-components) would be better advice than your answer, but OP already admitted their code is complex. Memoizing the `renderItem` function doesn't change the `Line` component complexity.